# How to count for between two dates in 2 colums with different row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet with 2 columns with dates and one with a Room #:

| Date In | Date Out | Room No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/3/2023 | 2/5/2023 | Room 1 |
| 2/5/2023 | 2/8/2023 | Room 1 |
| 2/8/2023 | 2/10/2023 | Room 1 |
| 3/23/2023 | 3/26/2023 | Room 1 |
| 3/30/2023 | 3/31/2023 | Room 5 |
| 4/6/2023 | 4/8/2023 | Room 6 |
| 4/13/2023 | 4/14/2023 | Room 1 |
| 4/19/2023 | 4/21/2023 | Room 2 |
| 4/23/2023 | 4/26/2023 | Room 3 |

I want to count how many `date out` - next `date in` for the same Room # = 0 or more than 1.

Is there any way of doing this?

Any suggestions are gratefully accepted. thanks
[image: Example]

[Example using match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCbsa.png)

Answer (score 1):

*You may try these formula:*

[image]

---

Formula in H27: `=SUM(IF(C26:C34=F25, IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B26:B34, A26:A34, 0)), 1, 0)))`

Formula in H28: `=SUM(IF(C26:C34=F25, IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B26:B34, A26:A34, 0)), 0, 1)))`

---

*If you are using higher version of Excel like 2021 or 365 then you may try this also.*

H27: `=COUNT(FILTER(B26:B34, (C26:C34=F25)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B26:B34, A26:A34, 0))=TRUE)))`

H28: `=COUNT(FILTER(B26:B34, (C26:C34=F25)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B26:B34, A26:A34, 0))=FALSE)))`

---

**N.B.**

- Cell `F25` has Criteria, and is editable better create a Drop Down.
- Adjust cell references as needed.

Comment: Hi, i try out but it return as 0.. .my formula=SUM(IF($C$2:$C$20=F3, IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$20, $B$2:$B$20, 0)), 0,1))).. can help to advice where when wrong? thanks

Comment: @Chris ,,, nothing wrong with the formula what we both are using ,,,,, once you try to finish the formula with **CTRL+SHIFT+Enter** ,,,, will work ☺

Comment: it works but wrong calculations.. @Rajesh

Comment: @Chris   if possible share the Sample data Workbook with me ,,,, either using Google Drive  or DropBox ,,,,  since with the data I've used getting expected results☺

Comment: @ Rajesh Sinha sorry for late reply .. here is the link to google drive https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ic_QsrC1RIwwGKkDOfatCQjm_ZBsxZSH/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113381948000321751126&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @Chris  [Check this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xXrUByjW7OkONYN8pc3YlGUs5TMKzJzivrRcOFhoQEc/edit#gid=1460441952)  and the formula I've written in G3:I4  and in L3:N14  also   Q3:S14 ,,,,,, Month name in Col K & P are Date formatted as text ,,.

Answer (score 0):

I only noticed now that you tagged Excel 2007:

You may want to use this for that version:
`=SUM(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B10&F3,A2:A10&F3,0)))`
`=SUM(ISNA(MATCH(B2:B10&C2:C10,A2:A10&C2:C10,0))*(C2:C10=F2))-1`

**!!** Note that both formulas require being entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`

The first returns the number of results where the Room in column C equals the value in `F3` where the Date Out value is also found in the Date In column where the room equals `F3`.

The second returns the number where the Date In value doesn't equal the Date out value doesn't equal where the room equals `F3`. But since there's always a last value that doesn't have a later date; we subtract 1 of the summed total.

If you use Office 365 you could achieve the following:

Maybe my answer is not in the format you requested, but I think this may be giving you more insight:

```
=LET(sorted,SORT(A2:C10,{3,2}),
     room,TAKE(sorted,,-1),
     roomcomp,(DROP(room,-1)=DROP(room,1)),
     indate,DROP(TAKE(sorted,,1),1),
     outdate,DROP(INDEX(sorted,,2),-1),
VSTACK(HSTACK(A1:C1,
              "next date in "&{"=",">"}&" previous date out"),
       IFERROR(HSTACK(sorted,
                      (roomcomp)*(outdate=indate),
                      (roomcomp)*(outdate<indate)),
               "")))
```

It will show the same range, but sorted by Room, then date out and the result by row for the next indate being equal to or greater than the previous outdate. That way you also see for which date(s) the conditions apply.

[image]

Basically what it does is `=(B2:B9=A3:A10)*(C2:C9=C3:C10)` and `=(B2:B9<A3:A10)*(C2:C9=C3:C10)` but on the Range B2:C10 sorted by Room then by Date (out).

Another way of creating more insight is to show the last day out where the day in and day out are consecutive for the same room:

`=LET(a,A2:A10,b,B2:B10,c,C2:C10,r,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),MAP(a,b,c,LAMBDA(u,v,w,REDUCE(v,r,LAMBDA(x,y,XLOOKUP(x&w,a&w,b,x))))))`

[image]

Comment: @Chris I updated my answer to include a Excel 2007 solution. I just noticed the tag, therefore my previous answer(s) can not be applied to your version of Excel. I kept them, because it may help others, or may help you decide to update to Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

Use =DAYS(end,start)
Formula In C1, A1 is start date and B1 is end date
=DAYS(B1,A1)